# How to determine which web service should be used alongside php to call the pastebin api?

Tags: php

I want to develop an app using the api provided by pastebin.com , using php . What I am not able to figure out is which web service like SOAP , etc , should be used to do this work ?

Comment: what does pastebin's documentation say to use?

Comment: There is hardly any documentation regarding what to use . Thus the question .

Comment: http://pastebin.com/api.php.  Says it's a simple `post` request.  This means regular `curl` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), or `sockets` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to send specially crafted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says to submit a POST request, which means this is a REST-ful HTTP interface. No SOAP, no WSDLs, just HTTP like web browsers work.

All you need is some code capable of sending HTTP requests.

In PHP, the simplest one that comes with most installs is the cURL library.

Example of sending a POST is in the second comment of the manual page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php